# forgein key problems

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am building a survey application it consists of 3 check boxes and a question when butten is clicked it submits the answer but recently i added a foreign key to my table and i am getting this error when i try to submit the answer:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_test`.`tblanswers`, CONSTRAINT `tblanswers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`answerid`) REFERENCES `credentials` (`cid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `tblanswers` (`questionid`, `answerA`, `answerB`, `answerC`, `comment`, `cid`) VALUES ('melynas ', 'melynas ', 'baltas', 'geltonas', 'testas', NULL)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\Surva\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

can anyone help me out here and explain what i did wrong? tnx in advance.

**table structure**

i forgot to mention i am using codeigniter.

**Credentials table**

```
IF NOT EXISTS `credentials` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `second_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=98 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `credentials`
--
ALTER TABLE `credentials`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `credentials_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `tblanswers` (`answerid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION
```

**tblanswers**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblanswers` (
  `answerid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answerA` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `answerB` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `answerC` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=205 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: can you show thw resule of this query? `DESC tblanswers` and  `DESC credentials`

Comment: If you put the foreign Key in your current Table then you can't insert record in foreign column which in not in primary column.

Comment: sorry i daunt understand i am new to this

Comment: can u explain this in more detail  Rohit R.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just mean that you are inserting a value on a child table which does not exist on the parent table. Consider the following schema.

```
Table1
- ID (PK)
- Name

Table2
- RecID (PK)
- OtherColumn
- Table1ID (FK)
```

The `Table2` is the child table which column `Table1ID` refrences on `Table1` column `ID`.

```
Table1 
ID      Name
1       John
2       Hello

Table2
RecID   OtherColumn     Table1ID
1       asd             1
2       qwe             2
3       rty             1
```

As you can see the values of `Table2`.`Table1ID` are all present on `Table1`.`ID` because it is dependent on `Table1`.

When you try to `INSERT` a value of `Table2`.`Table1ID` that doesn't exist on `Table1`, it will generate an error because foreign key enforces referential integrity.

Example of query that is expected to fail.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (RecID, OtherColumn, Table1ID)
VALUES (1, 'xxx', 10)
```

The reason is because the value `10` of column `Table1ID` doesn't exists on `Table1`.`ID`.

Comment: can you tell me what i can do to fix this ? i am still learning how to work with MySQL.

Comment: sure, if you can give the table definition of table `tblanswers` and `credentials`.

Comment: yes i want to see that. and also the query you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the foreign Key in your current Table then you can't insert record in foreign column which in not in primary column.

Like you have table

Tbl1 primary key: id

```
      id    username    password
      1     test1       123456
      2     test2       123
```

your second table

Tbl2   foreign key :t1_id

```
      ti_id    fname      address
      1        temp       strret
      3        tesp3      strrr
```

you can't insert second record because there is no column in Tbl1 which has id=3

this type of problem in your case